# how to set draggable to false on mobile for framer motion OR change dimensions of dragging responsively for different screen sizes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, responsive, draggable, framer-motion

I have a draggable component in my React app that is only draggable within certain dimensions.
However, on mobile, those dimensions go beyond the screen, and the user can drag the component out of the screen and never get it back.

I wanted to know if there was a way to make the component un-draggable for mobile devices. Even more ideally, I wanted to know if there is a way to change the dimensions within which the component is draggable for different screen sizes. (responsiveness)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the limit where they can drag with Drag Constraints

Docs: https://www.framer.com/api/motion/gestures/#draggableprops.dragconstraints

And then dynamically change that based on screen size either by

1. Binding the constraints to the pixels values of the screen size
2. Or passing the ref of a containing div that is responsive to the dragConstraints prop of the draggable element

```
 const constraintsRef = useRef(null);

 return (
   <MotionConstraints ref={constraintsRef}>
       <MotionBox drag dragConstraints={constraintsRef}>
         Drag Me
       </MotionBox>
     </MotionConstraints>
 )
```

A working example of #2: https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-constraints-on-a-draggable-element-jqvu5?file=/src/App.tsx